# ESXi single ip setup

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi

I have a ESXi server that has just one ip, which is assigned to the host. Is there a way to map certain host ports to the vm's that it runs, or should I just order extra ip's at my hoster?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you'll have to order more IPs.

Comment: Thanks, done, but now having routing issues. In case you're interested: http://serverfault.com/questions/534213/additional-ips-wont-route-on-esxi

Answer (score -1):

You can set up a router VM and confiure NAT to masquerade all the traffic with your IP.

Apparently there's a cisco product called Cisco Cloud Services Router 1000V, which can do that. There's a free limited version of that. Or you can do it with almost any OS you like.

Of course you should keep in mind that in case router VM will be switched off - you won't have an access to ESXi host to bring it back up. And in datacenter environment it's really tricky to remove the IP from esxi host to put it to router.

Comment: But he'll need the management interface to have an IP, in his case the ONLY IP, sure if you've got two IP you could setup a router (pfsense?) and assign that second IP to the external interface of the router and NAT the internal address space but he will need at least two IPs, there's no way to get the management interface of the host to act as a router.

Comment: I see no problem in using external ip for management and NAT in the same time. Of course one would need a private subnet between router and other VMs.

Comment: Sorry but you're wrong - if you think you're right tell me EXACTLY how you'd use a single IP for management and NAT.

Comment: ok, let me make it clear.
There's at least 2 management IPs - let's say IP1 is external interface of router and IP2 is for esxi management console. IP2 could be also in private subnet behind the router. Not the best way to do it, but stil feasible.

Comment: So you're admitting that you were wrong and you can't do this with a single IP right? if so then perhaps you might want to remove your downvote to my correct answer?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't me. Neither I admit that I'm wrong. It's one of the cases when 'you can' doesn't mean 'you should'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10321/discussion-between-dukelion-and-chopper3)