# Additional IP's won't route on ESXi

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi

I have an ESXi 5.1.0 server with one ip; needed additional ip's for the Guests, so I ordered 3. Now, when I try to assign the ip's to the guests, they are unable to access the internet.

vSphere -> Configuration -> Networking

I assume there's something wrong here, but it's just as ovh configged it. There is a management network with the initial ip (?.?.209.?) and the new ip's are in a different range (?.?.149.?).

The two VM's are on the VM Network. I've assigned one of the additional ip's to a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, made sure the mask was 255.255.255.0 and the gateway was the same as the ip, but with 254 as the last byte (as ovh states), but no dice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gateway set up properly? Does ping work at all (like to the ESXi host)?

Comment: Much more detail please Nick, MUCH :)

Comment: Don't know what else there is to tell. Pinging anything besides it's own ip gives destination host unreachable, which makes me believe it must be something on the ESXi site, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Show us your vSwitch/Port-Groups setup, how your VNICs are done, ifconfig output etc.

Comment: It was all due to OVH's way of routing.

You need to create a vMware MAC Mapping for your guest and assign the mac address they generate to allow it to route.

Here's how: http://guide.ovh.com/DedieMac

Their dutch website is terrible and full with dead links, so I'm sure other people will have the same issues :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all due to OVH's way of routing.

You need to create a vMware MAC Mapping for your guest and assign the mac address they generate to allow it to route.

Here's how: http://guide.ovh.com/DedieMac

Their dutch website is terrible and full with dead links, so I'm sure other people will have the same issues :P